# Get Url from other apps android Studio

Tags: java, android

Get Url from other  sources/apps.
like when you click share button on YouTube you see a bunch of apps.

How can I implement this ability in my app .

Example -
open url with x app .

I have searched on internet but found nothing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, In you manifest, put this in the first activity that will be open when your app launch like your SplashActivity

```
 <intent-filter android:label="testing">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.youtube.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

And retrieve the data from the your by putting the below in the onCreateView() of the Activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity)
    
    //this is what you need here
    val action: String? = intent?.action
    val data: Uri? = intent?.data
   }
```

For more clarification. check [deep-linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)

Answer (score 0):

**Add intent filters for incoming links**

```
  <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_http_gizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.example.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
        <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
    </intent-filter>
```

**Read data from incoming intents**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main)

    val action: String? = intent?.action
    val data: Uri? = intent?.data
}
```

Just change your link in the intent filter you want to accept for your application.